# How do I change the element of only one list in a Python dictionary of lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've made a dictionary in **Python** that's composed of 4 lists as values, with a single letter key for each list. When I try to change a value in only *one* of the lists by referencing dict_name[key][list index], I'm finding that that same index is changing in the lists for *every one* of the keys in the dictionary.

Here's an example of the **starting dictionary**:

```
my_dict = {'A': [0, 0, 0, 0], 'C': [0, 0, 0, 0], 'G': [0, 0, 0, 0], 'T': [0, 0, 0, 0]}
```

And then I try to **change a single value** in one of the lists by iterating with a for-loop:

```
test_string = 'WXTZ'
k = len(test_string)

for i in range(k):
    if test_string[i] == 'T':
        my_dict['T'][i] += 1
```

But the **output I'm getting** doesn't make sense:

```
print(my_dict) = {'A': [0, 0, 1, 0], 'C': [0, 0, 1, 0], 'G': [0, 0, 1, 0], 'T': [0, 0, 1, 0]}
```

I would think that this **should return the following instead**:

```
print(my_dict) = {'A': [0, 0, 0, 0], 'C': [0, 0, 0, 0], 'G': [0, 0, 0, 0], 'T': [0, 0, 1, 0]}
```

Has anyone else experienced something like this before? How would I change only the 'T' list in this case with such a loop, if not this way?

I'm in Python 3 with Atom on Windows 10 if that's worth knowing. Thanks!

**EDIT**: A few of you asked about **the code that I used to create my_dict**. Including that below for reference:

```
holder = []
my_dict = {}
k = len(string)
for i in range(k):
    holder.append(0)

for char in 'ACGT':
    my_dict[char] = holder
```

Comment: You should show the code where you create `my_dict`. It looks like you used a single list and referenced it many times. For a discussion see: [How do I clone a list so that it doesn't change unexpectedly after assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-do-i-clone-a-list-so-that-it-doesnt-change-unexpectedly-after-assignment)

Comment: your code produces the correct output. I suspect the way you are creating `my_dict` actually results in *the same list* being used as a value for each of the keys

Comment: As an aside, this should probably just be `my_dict['T'][test_string.index('T')] += 1` if you know `'T'` is in your string

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That works if T is in the string, but if it is only one time in it

Comment: @PlainRavioli yes, you are correct

Comment: @Mark thank you! That seemed to be exactly what was happening -- each of the 4 lists in the dictionary I had created were all referring to the same list that I used to create the dictionary. Great to know for future reference :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably is what mark sugested in the comment, you are using the same list object in all the values of the dict.

I tried exactly what you exemplified:

`my_dict = {'A': [0, 0, 0, 0], 'C': [0, 0, 0, 0], 'G': [0, 0, 0, 0], 'T': [0, 0, 0, 0]}`

`my_dict['T'][0] = 1`

And that changed to:

`{'A': [0, 0, 0, 0], 'C': [0, 0, 0, 0], 'G': [0, 0, 0, 0], 'T': [1, 0, 0, 0]}`

Try initializing the dict as that:

`my_dict = {'A': [0, 0, 0, 0], 'C': [0, 0, 0, 0], 'G': [0, 0, 0, 0], 'T': [0, 0, 0, 0]}`

Or using different list objects like:

`list1=[0,0,0,0]`

`list2=[0,0,0,0]`

`dict={'A': list1, 'B':list2}`